Issues with Routing on Tomcat with Spring Boot and React Application
I'm facing an issue with routing on Tomcat. I'm receiving a ready-made .war file which contains the built files from a React app located in the resources/static folder.
After rebuilding with Maven, I get the .war file which I place in the tomcat/webapps directory on the server. I start the service using /etc/init.d, but I get a 404 error even when I provide the exact path to the index.html. On Tomcat, the index.html is located in apka/WEB-INF/classes/static, and there is an assets folder containing CSS, JS files, etc.
So, my question is what and where should I edit to display index.html when accessing address-ip:port/apka and ensure every endpoint functions correctly?
For context, I also have Logicaldoc installed and it works fine. I tried configuring application.properties with classpath and setting welcome-file in pom.xml, but I suspect the issue lies somewhere in Spring Boot's configuration.
I'm using Java 21.0.3 LTS, Maven 3.8.7, SpringBoot CLI v3.3.1, React ^18.3.1, Tomcat 9.0.91, and Debian 12.
Thank you for your help!
I tried editing application.properties by adding:
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/

I also tried creating the following controller:
@Controller
public class ResourceController {

    @GetMapping("/apka/**")
    public String apka() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}

I copied all files from assets to src/main/resources/static and edited vite.config.js but gave up on that. I also tried this:
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/{x:[\\w\\-]+}", "/{x:^(?!api$).*$}/*/{y:[\\w\\-]+}" })
    public String getIndex() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}


When I navigate to https://address_ip:port/apka, I get a 404 error: "The requested resource [/apka/] is not available". There are no errors regarding "apka" in the catalina.out file

just answered a similar question here, Spring Boot 3+ requires Tomcat 10.1+. Might not be your only issue, but to start with - why are you not simply using the embedded tomcat?

@J. Asgarov Regarding the installation of tomcat 10.* I had problems with javax.* for jakarta.* I got a lot of errors and I gave up :/ so what should I do to make it work on 9.* just in case?

downgrade to spring boot 2 :) You should however be going in the opposite direction and update your code to work with version 3 (should be as simple as replacing all javax with jakarta)

Okay i downloaded tool migration from github and I will report on my progress. Thanks :D

Hi, I installed Tomcat 11.0.0-M22 and am using the tool from link I enter the command: java -jar jakartaee-migration-1.0.8-shaded.jar apka.war apka-migrated.war Then, I upload the .war file through the manager app, and it shows status: ok. When I go to http://ip_address:port/apka, I still can't see index.html after deploying the application, which was rebuilt with React. In comparison, the LogicalDoc application with a .jsp extension works correctly. What am I doing wrong? I receive the status:  Status 404 /apka/ is not available
